# Can't get containers to expand vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an outer container element to expand vertically to encompass the inner elements, but it doesn't seem to want to. In that screenshot I've got an outer div (I used jumbotron in that example but it does the same thing no matter what the class), with a video and some text inside it, but it doesn't expand to contain the inner elements for some reason. Source:

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <video class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" muted autoplay loop>
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        text here<br/>
        text here<br/>
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

***Screenshot***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="jumbotron clearfix">
```

And you should be fine.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjDqj/

Comment: clearfix did it, thank you. I wonder why it was even needed, though? I'm using 100% out of the box example code, nothing in the pockets but knives and lint.

Comment: You get the very same thing if you apply to the jumbotron class overflow: hidden; Check out the css for the .clearfix on bootstrap's css. This should explain it:http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html and http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks right to me unfortunately... But your screenshot looks like there is a weird float or clearing issue.

Try adding the class `clearfix` to your jumbotron div.

Better yet, could you make a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) example?

Comment: It does the same thing in the above comment's JSFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/pjDqj/. So it wasn't just me, I guess. Anyway I'm glad I asked, I never would have figured that out.

Comment: Yeah, I literally wrote my answer the same time lol. It showed up after I posted mine :)